# Multiple OR conditions inside CUBEVALUE Formula

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to add multiple condition inside a single member expression of a cubevalue formula. For example, =CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel", "[Data_Table].[Column_Name].[HERE either Value1, or Value2 or Value3 etc]")
The formula would look like this
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[risk indicator]","[Company].[Account].[Operation]"

So I want to have the risk indicator value for multiple operations for the same company and same account. So OR(Operation1, Operation2, Operation3).
I hope it is clear
Thanks

Comment: You say you want to choose between multiple values, but don't explain what the criteria is. Sample data and the expected outcome, as well as what you have tried so far would be useful

Comment: Also what result do you expect if more than one country is present in the data?

Comment: @Rory please check the modification

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: We can't see your file, so you will really need to provide some sample data and the expected output. The last sentence describes an `AND`, not an `OR` and kind of makes things even less clear. `=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[risk indicator]","[Company].[Account].[Operation1] + CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[risk indicator]","[Company].[Account].[Operation2] + CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[risk indicator]","[Company].[Account].[Operation3])` maybe?